# how to get inspect element code using c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get text from URL but text is not shown in source code. I can see it only in inspect element . Is there anyway, in C# to get the contents of Inspect element of the page. I try htmlagilitypack with c# but give null exception.

```
Class1 class1obj = new Class1(); 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);  
request.Method = "GET"; 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{ 
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
    StreamReader readStream = null; 
    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream); 
    else
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)); 
    class1obj.Data1 = readStream.ReadToEnd(); 
    Console.WriteLine(class1obj.Data1);
    readStream.Close();
 }

 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(class1obj.Data1);
 // HtmlNodeCollection tables2 =     doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='tv_ch_detila h_scroll_detail']");
 HtmlNode rows2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='sub_text']");
 Console.WriteLine(rows2.InnerText);
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: url:  http://www.whatsonindia.com/#!/Tv-Listings

Comment: okay, and what element you want to select?

Comment: program schedule inside the class class="channelProgrammeRow ng-scope odd" but this class will not appear in source code only in inspect element code

Comment: well, I don't seem to find "program schedule" in here... do you want to grab "tv_guide_container"? can you give me a snap of what you want to extract?

Comment: ya i want to grab text(program name and start time ) inside class timeline inside tv_guide_container

Comment: If the content is dynamically generated with javascript, you will need to a browser or emulator to do that, watin, webbrowser control, PhantomJS, and/or similar. In some specific cases you may be able to get the directly URL that brings the data but needs some knowledge to investigate the requests.

Comment: please tell how to parse inspect element code using  c#

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of encrypted data that is being loaded dynamically after the page loads. The Url getting the said data is:

http://www.whatsonindia.com/appi/user?channelgenre=all&context=applicationname%3Dsourcebits%3Bheadendid%3D0&dateselected=0&mode=getTVGuideInfo&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&starthour=0&totalhrdata=24&userid=-1

It contains a "data" and a "pki" node in JSON format. You can't just reply on waiting for the page being completely loaded.

Instead you can just make a request to the given url and decrypt the text. This is the only way that I can assume here. The unreliable way is to load the url in a Web Browser control and wait for few seconds (say 5-10) assuming that all the contents are loaded and then parse the DocumentText or web browser control.

I managed to get this JSON data for tv-programmes:

```
{
"gettvguidewithgenre": {
    "tvguideprogrammewithgenrelist": [
      {
        "programmeid": "10000000934920000",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T00:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T01:40:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Ghatak",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549824121",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T01:40:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T03:50:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Time Limit-36 Ghante",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Drama",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549816018",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T03:50:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T05:40:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Volcano High",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549673440",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T05:40:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T08:10:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Maa Beti",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Drama",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "10000001008740000",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T08:10:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T11:05:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Dus",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549644318",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T11:05:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T13:55:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Money Hai Toh Honey Hai",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Comedy",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549646489",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T13:55:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T17:15:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Farz",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Drama",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549709799",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T17:15:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T20:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Action Replayy",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Comedy",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549664553",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T20:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T23:25:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Indian",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549781987",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T23:25:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-26T00:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000110000",
        "programmename": "Narsimha - Man Of Power",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Drama",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549741259",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T00:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T02:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "The Dirty Picture",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Drama",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T02:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T02:40:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T02:40:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T03:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T03:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T03:25:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T03:25:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T03:40:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T03:40:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T04:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549867681",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T04:00:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T04:25:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000540000",
        "programmename": "Extraa Shots Special",
        "m2ecategoryname": "TV Show",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Entertainment",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "10000001078790000",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T18:08:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T20:30:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000210000",
        "programmename": "Aadmi",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549651842",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T20:30:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-25T23:16:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000210000",
        "programmename": "Dum",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Action",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      },
      {
        "programmeid": "30000000549828153",
        "starttime": "2014-02-25T23:16:00+05:30",
        "endtime": "2014-02-26T00:00:00+05:30",
        "channelid": "10000000000210000",
        "programmename": "Aakhri Baazi",
        "m2ecategoryname": "Film",
        "m2esubcategoryname": "Romance",
        "Isrecommended": "1"
      }
    ],
    "channelinfo": [
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000110000",
        "ChannelName": "STAR GOLD",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000110000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000540000",
        "ChannelName": "MAX",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000540000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000620000",
        "ChannelName": "TEN SPORTS",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000620000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000700000",
        "ChannelName": "HBO",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000700000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000100000",
        "ChannelName": "STAR MOVIES",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000100000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000080000",
        "ChannelName": "STAR PLUS",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000080000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      },
      {
        "ChannelID": "10000000000210000",
        "ChannelName": "ZEE CINEMA",
        "LCN": "0",
        "Operator_Id": "2645",
        "logofileurl": "http://images.whatsonindia.com/WhatsOnTv/Images/applicationchannellogo/10000000000210000.png",
        "ischannelfavorite": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It uses CryptoJS for encryption and decryption.

Comment: how you get this link? can you explain this?

Comment: in Chrome Console. Couldn't find any way other than loading the content and waiting for ajax to dynamically add the content thought. Will update my answer as soon I get through this.

Comment: how you derypt this json code please tell what code you are using

Comment: how you decrypt this text from url

Comment: I didn't note all the steps but I can explain you what I did. I parsed the JSON data from the url I've mentioned above managed to decrypt it using CryptoJS library they're using. The decrypt function is there in one of referenced JS libraries named "application... .js". Search for "CryptoJS.AES.decrypt"... and you'll find it.

Comment: please tell which library i need?